# Perl perl-5.8.8-38 Vs perl-5.10.1-136.el6.x86_64 Thread Memory leak

Tags: multithreading, perl, memory-leaks

I am kind of new to perl. But I see this memory leak happening in thread implementation. 
Versions compared
perl-5.8.8-38
Vs
perl-5.10.1-136.el6.x86_64

code that I executed is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $pid            = "$$";
my $profileCommand = "/export/user_share/builder/cyborgtools/process_profiler/bin/process_profiler $pid";
print "$profileCommand\n";
system("$profileCommand 2>&1 >> /var/log/processProfiler_exec.log &");

#use threads('stack_size' => 5242880);
use threads;
use threads::shared;

my $curr_size = threads->get_stack_size();

my @threads;

my @cmds = ( "Anugraha", "Rinky", "Pratyush", "Shubham" );
for my $cmd (@cmds) {
    my $thread = threads->new( \&execCmd, $cmd );
    push( @threads, $thread );
    my $size = $thread->get_stack_size();
    print "Invoked stack for $cmd with stack size $size\n";
}

foreach (@threads) {
    $_->join;
}

print "Thread main entering into sleep mode (10 secs) after thread join\n";
sleep(10);
exit;

sub execCmd {
    my ($threadCmd) = @_;
    print "In execCmd for thread $threadCmd\n";
    print "Entering sleep mode (5secs) for thread with cmd $threadCmd\n";
    sleep(5);
}
```

Output execution of above code 
Perl Version : perl-5.8.8-38

```
[root@my-machine ~]# ./temp.pl 
/tmp/process_profiler 7216
Invoked stack for Anugraha with stack size 10485760
In execCmd for thread Anugraha
Entering sleep mode (5secs) for thread with cmd Anugraha
Invoked stack for Rinky with stack size 10485760
In execCmd for thread Rinky
Entering sleep mode (5secs) for thread with cmd Rinky
Invoked stack for Pratyush with stack size 10485760
Invoked stack for Shubham with stack size 10485760
In execCmd for thread Pratyush
Entering sleep mode (5secs) for thread with cmd Pratyush
In execCmd for thread Shubham
Entering sleep mode (5secs) for thread with cmd Shubham
Thread main entering into sleep mode (10 secs) after thread join
[root@my-machine ~]#
```

Output execution of above code 
Perl Version : perl-5.10.1-136.el6.x86_64

```
[asinha@hydra-cyborgmother perl_thread_testing]$ ./temp.pl 
/export/user_share/builder/cyborgtools/process_profiler/bin/process_profiler 9566
Invoked stack for Anugraha with stack size 10485760
In execCmd for thread Anugraha
Entering sleep mode (5secs) for thread with cmd Anugraha
Invoked stack for Rinky with stack size 10485760
In execCmd for thread Rinky
Entering sleep mode (5secs) for thread with cmd Rinky
Invoked stack for Pratyush with stack size 10485760
In execCmd for thread Pratyush
Entering sleep mode (5secs) for thread with cmd Pratyush
Invoked stack for Shubham with stack size 10485760
In execCmd for thread Shubham
Entering sleep mode (5secs) for thread with cmd Shubham
Thread main entering into sleep mode (10 secs) after thread join
[asinha@hydra-cyborgmother perl_thread_testing]$
```

I have a indigeneous memory profiling utility as
process_profiler
which basically traverses the PID in proc filesystem task directory to see threads
and brings out Memory information.

Output of this profiler for code mentioned above on PERL version perl-5.8.8-38

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date                  PID   VmPeak   VmSize   VmHWM   VmRSS   VmData   VmStk   CmdLine   Parent
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2014-09-26 05:02:33   7216   225088KB   192136KB   5040KB   5040KB   110780KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 05:02:34   7216   225088KB   192136KB   5040KB   5040KB   110780KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 05:02:34   7220   225088KB   192136KB   5040KB   5040KB   110780KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 05:02:34   7225   225088KB   192136KB   5040KB   5040KB   110780KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 05:02:34   7227   225088KB   192136KB   5040KB   5040KB   110780KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 05:02:34   7231   225088KB   192136KB   5040KB   5040KB   110780KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 05:02:35   7216   225088KB   192136KB   5040KB   5040KB   110780KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 05:02:35   7220   225088KB   192136KB   5040KB   5040KB   110780KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 05:02:35   7225   225088KB   192136KB   5040KB   5040KB   110780KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 05:02:35   7227   225088KB   192136KB   5040KB   5040KB   110780KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 05:02:35   7231   225088KB   192136KB   5040KB   5040KB   110780KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 05:02:36   7216   225088KB   192136KB   5040KB   5040KB   110780KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 05:02:36   7220   225088KB   192136KB   5040KB   5040KB   110780KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 05:02:36   7225   225088KB   192136KB   5040KB   5040KB   110780KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 05:02:36   7227   225088KB   192136KB   5040KB   5040KB   110780KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 05:02:36   7231   225088KB   192136KB   5040KB   5040KB   110780KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 05:02:37   7216   225088KB   192136KB   5040KB   5040KB   110780KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 05:02:37   7220   225088KB   192136KB   5040KB   5040KB   110780KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 05:02:37   7225   225088KB   192136KB   5040KB   5040KB   110780KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 05:02:37   7227   225088KB   192136KB   5040KB   5040KB   110780KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 05:02:37   7231   225088KB   192136KB   5040KB   5040KB   110780KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 05:02:38   7216   225088KB   181220KB   5040KB   4948KB   99864KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 05:02:39   7216   225088KB   181220KB   5040KB   4948KB   99864KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 05:02:40   7216   225088KB   181220KB   5040KB   4948KB   99864KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 05:02:41   7216   225088KB   181220KB   5040KB   4948KB   99864KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 05:02:42   7216   225088KB   181220KB   5040KB   4948KB   99864KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 05:02:43   7216   225088KB   181220KB   5040KB   4948KB   99864KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 05:02:44   7216   225088KB   181220KB   5040KB   4948KB   99864KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 05:02:45   7216   225088KB   181220KB   5040KB   4948KB   99864KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 05:02:46   7216   225088KB   181220KB   5040KB   4948KB   99864KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 05:02:47   7216   225088KB   181220KB   5040KB   4948KB   99864KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
```

Output of this profiler for code mentioned above on PERL version  perl-5.10.1-136.el6.x86_64

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date                  PID   VmPeak   VmSize   VmHWM   VmRSS   VmData   VmStk   CmdLine   Parent
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2014-09-26 10:01:28   9566   129820KB   282600KB   5540KB   5540KB   306888KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 10:01:29   9566   500636KB   435100KB   5540KB   5540KB   306888KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 10:01:29   9574   500636KB   435100KB   5540KB   5540KB   306888KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 10:01:29   9577   500636KB   435100KB   5540KB   5540KB   306888KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 10:01:29   9581   500636KB   435100KB   5540KB   5540KB   306888KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 10:01:29   9583   500636KB   435100KB   5540KB   5540KB   306888KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 10:01:30   9566   500636KB   435100KB   5540KB   5540KB   306888KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 10:01:30   9574   500636KB   435100KB   5540KB   5540KB   306888KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 10:01:30   9577   500636KB   435100KB   5540KB   5540KB   306888KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 10:01:30   9581   500636KB   435100KB   5540KB   5540KB   306888KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 10:01:30   9583   500636KB   435100KB   5540KB   5540KB   306888KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 10:01:31   9566   500636KB   435100KB   5540KB   5540KB   306888KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 10:01:31   9574   500636KB   435100KB   5540KB   5540KB   306888KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 10:01:31   9577   500636KB   435100KB   5540KB   5540KB   306888KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 10:01:31   9581   500636KB   435100KB   5540KB   5540KB   306888KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 10:01:31   9583   500636KB   435100KB   5540KB   5540KB   306888KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 10:01:33   9566   500636KB   435100KB   5540KB   5540KB   306888KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 10:01:33   9574   500636KB   435100KB   5540KB   5540KB   306888KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 10:01:33   9577   500636KB   435100KB   5540KB   5540KB   306888KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 10:01:33   9581   500636KB   435100KB   5540KB   5540KB   306888KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 10:01:33   9583   500636KB   435100KB   5540KB   5540KB   306888KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   
2014-09-26 10:01:34   9566   500636KB   424808KB   5540KB   5532KB   296596KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 10:01:35   9566   500636KB   424808KB   5540KB   5532KB   296596KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 10:01:36   9566   500636KB   424808KB   5540KB   5532KB   296596KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 10:01:37   9566   500636KB   424808KB   5540KB   5532KB   296596KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 10:01:38   9566   500636KB   424808KB   5540KB   5532KB   296596KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 10:01:39   9566   500636KB   424808KB   5540KB   5532KB   296596KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 10:01:40   9566   500636KB   424808KB   5540KB   5532KB   296596KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 10:01:41   9566   500636KB   424808KB   5540KB   5532KB   296596KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 10:01:42   9566   500636KB   424808KB   5540KB   5532KB   296596KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
2014-09-26 10:01:43   9566   500636KB   424808KB   5540KB   5532KB   296596KB   88KB   /usr/bin/perl   *
```

I think there is memory lead happening on perl-5.10.1-136.el6.x86_64 .
Am I missing something here?

---

EDIT

ulimit for max stack size in both the cases is 10240KB. Both are linux (x86_64) machines with 8GB RAM and 16GB swap.
kernel for perl version perl-5.8.8-38 = 2.6.18-308.11.1.el5.x86_64
kernel for perl version perl-5.10.1-136.el6.x86_64 =  2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64

Comment: (1) I can see how peak usage is higher, but can't see any leak (increasing figures) and the RSS seems stable and comparable. Can you be more explicit about why you think there is a leak. (2) Grab a download of perlbrew and try it with a recent Perl - if there is a problem in 5.10 there's not going to be a bugfix, is there?

Comment: @RichardHuxton My concern is VmData. Yes, VmRSS and VmHWM are consistent and low. However, VmData is too high and differ by around 3times between the two versions.

Comment: It might be "too high", but it's not increasing steadily as far as I can see, so it's not a memory leak. Besides, like I said, there's nothing anyone can do about it. Perl 5.10's last release was five years ago. Try a recent version if it's causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

One of the things that catches people out with perl is memory usage. Perl does it's own memory allocation and garbage collection, so if you watch it from an OS perspective... you'll get a distorted picture. Usually you don't need to worry about 'tidying up' but you do need to be slightly careful to ensure that things are scoped appropriately. Globals are classic sources of memory leaks, for example, because you can keep adding elements to an array.

Pretty fundamentally though - as noted in the comments - your RSS doesn't change much over time. It'd be hard to spot a memory leak over a matter of seconds anyway. It therefore doesn't look like one - but it might be a bit more obvious with a much longer loop and cycle.

Even if you have found a bug in perl 5.8 or 5.10... it's unlikely you'll find someone rush to analyse your bug, as they went end of life in 2008 and 2009 respectively. (And yes, I recognise this is an older post, it's still 5 years past EOL).

Latest perl (5.20 at time of writing) can be found here: http://www.cpan.org/src/README.html